# CDF of a rational function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What is the probability of $X \le -\frac{1}{2a}$, given that the density function of $X$ is:

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{ax^2+x+1}$$

I had this question in a test. It turns out I should've circled $\frac{1}{2}$ but I actually integrated this, using partial fractions, and came with a function that for any $a$ in its domain, is NOT a CDF:

$$F_X(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-4a}}\ln{\left|\dfrac{2ax+1-\sqrt{1-4a}}{2ax+1+\sqrt{1-4a}}\right|}$$

$F_X$ is not a CDF because its limit at $\infty$ is not $1$ but $0$.
Also, when I apply $x=-\frac{1}{2a}$ I get $\ln(1)=0$ too.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Did you type the density function correctly? It is written as $\frac{1}{a^2 + x+1}$, which has antiderivative $\ln\left|a^2 + x + 1\right|+C$.

Comment: You've left out some information: the domain.  This can't be a density function on all of $\mathbb{R}$, because it is undefined at $x=-1-a^2$ and is negative for $x<-1-a^2$.

Comment: My bad.. I edited the density function. @NickPeterson the exercise says that $f_X$ is defined on all of $R$

Answer (score 1):

Acutally, the integral is
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{ax^2+x+1} dx = \frac{2\tan^{-1}(\frac{2ax+1}{\sqrt{4a-1}})}{\sqrt{4a-1}} + c
\end{equation}

$c$ and $a$ can be get from assumptions of CDF in $-\infty, \infty$ (assuming that support is ($-\infty, \infty$)).

However more clever solution involves spotting that the distribution is symmetrical in relation to $-\frac{1}{2a}$.

This implies that the $F(-\frac{1}{2a}) = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Why is my $F_X$ not the integral?

Comment: Because you computed it wrong? How can I tell you where you made mistake if you didn't send whole computing schema? Compute derivative of my function and your's and you'll see.

Comment: E.g.your $F_X$ function do not have continous derivative in $x = \frac{\sqrt{1-4a}- 1}{2a}$ but on the other hand $f_X(x)$ is continous on whole real plane.